# Next.js with MySQL/Mongo backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sequelize.js, next.js

I have an existing Node.js/Express app which connects to 2 separate databases, it has a MySQL DB for all the relational and a MongoDB store for the non-relational vertical data.

It uses Sequelize and Mongoose and works absolutely swimmingly.

I've been looking at Next.js today and I'm pretty impressed, one of my pet peeves with React is actually how much bootstrapping there is and how much code it takes to achieve something simple. Next.js seems to solve some of those issues for me, so I'm willing to embrace it.

First issue - Is it possible to connect Next.js to existing DB's and read their objects directly in the view?

e.g. ./server.js:

```
const mongoDb = mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // MongoDB connection
const models = require('./models'); // Sequelize connection

app.prepare().then(() => {
    server.use((req, res, next) => {
        req.mongodb = mongoDb
        req.mysqldb = models
        // Logging req.mysqldb/req.mongodb at this point gives the correct result.
        next()
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })
})
```

./pages/index.js:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async function(req) {
    console.log(req.mongodb);
    console.log(req.mysqldb)

    // Example of what I want: req.mysqldb.users.findAll()....... to populate collection for this view
}
```

When the console statements are executed in the index.js page, they are logged as undefined.

Ideally I want to use the objects/ORM layer directly in the next.js templates, I do not want to have to call my own API internally, it seems like a huge waste of resources!

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference. getInitialProps gets passed in an object with one of the keys being `req`. So you're meant to do something like the following instead

```
// add the curly braces around req
Index.getInitialProps = async function({ req }) {
    // code
}
```

This is known as [Function Parameter Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and was introduced in ES6. What this accomplishes is similar to the following code

```
Index.getInitialProps = async function(_ref) {
    var req = _ref.req;
}
```

Meaning, it takes the value of `req` of the object that gets passed and uses that value.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently by the time the request gets to the template it has changed a bit! Namely, it is nested within another request object.

req.req.mongodb and req.req.mysqldb both work fine :).